# Can we get more info in the "Interesting questions" tab?

Tags: feature-request

Something like this:

[image]

For an old question with answers (and sometimes accepted answers), I have no clue as to why the post is up there and it is annoying to have to go through the entire post and look at the time stamps to figure it out. This becomes exponentially difficult on posts with high activity and lots of answers (a la Jon Skeet facts)

It would be nicer if the reason for the post being bumped is shown. Perhaps even make it a link, so that clicking it takes you right to the action that bumped it up.

Comment: Gah, another hard to find page.  Can you tell me where the link to that page is?  Can't find it anywhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Perhaps even make it a link, so that clicking it takes you right to the action that bumped it up.

Have you tried clicking where it says "8m ago"? Think you should, I do.

Comment: No had not, and that was good to know. +1

Comment: *Everything is a link* :) That said, I think it would be quite nice to prefix this info into the tool-tip, to avoid having to click through.